# When should I edit my answer vs creating a new one?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I asked a question, received a partial answer and found out the answer by myself later, so I created an answer.
One day after, I realized my answer was a mistake, so I wanted to to change it to the true solution. 
As I though editing it wouldn't reflect what truly happened, I decided to create a new answer and keep the old one (unaccepted, of course).

Is it the proper way to deal with this situation? Or would it be better if I edited it to the real solution?

It happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829182/keep-a-git-repository-backup-up-to-date/45872092#45872092)

Comment: *"I realized my answer was a mistake"* - the answer was a mistake, or was there a mistake __in__ the answer? If so, how big? *"editing it wouldn't reflect what truly happened"* - is that necessary to understand the correct answer for your question? ... Seeing your both answers in the linked question: I would have edited the initial answer and added a small paragraph about the issue in the first version and why that didn't work (like you did in the comment).

Comment: Well, technically there was the mistake in the answer. But as I wrote the answer based on someelse's contribution (that happened to not be the required solution), I feel that the answer is built around a mistake...
Ok, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Well in that case I would also leave a comment under the source answer to tell its OP that it didn't work (and still edit my own answer instead of adding a new one :P). But that's just my opinion, others may have a different one.

Comment: If there is a mistake in the answer and you keep it there - shouldn't you downvote it as well? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you found that your answer is wrong, you really have only two options:

- (preferably) edit post so it contains the correct answer.
- (alternatively) delete the wrong answer. If the answer is accepted, you need to raise a moderator flag to ask that it be deleted.

The only reason to post a new answer is if you have another approach to solve the problem and would like separate votes on both *correct* answers.

Note that it is considered abusive behavior to delete and post a new answer simply to avoid the downvotes on your original answer. The community will probably flag this if they see you making a habit of it.

There is no need to keep history of how you got to the answer. If the initial approach was something one would immediately try, you may add a sentence to the updated answer along the lines of *".... approach does not work because  …"*. Of course, if your answer is highly upvoted or was accepted, this is a good case to consider providing a longer explanation of why the original, obvious approach did not work.

Comment: Ok, thank you. There wasn't any vote on the answer, so this is probably a non-issue. Anyway, I edited the original answer and removed the second one I created in order to keep the original question "clean".